# datepicker not populating dates properly

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

Here is my jquery code:

```
   var unavailableDates = ["28-06-2011","22-12-2011","22-10-2011","22-02-2012",
                           "21-10-2011","21-07-2011","19-10-2011","18-11-2011",
                           "18-10-2011","18-05-2011","18-04-2011","17-12-2010",
                           "17-10-2011","14-10-2011","13-02-2012","12-11-2011",
                           "12-04-2011","09-12-2011","09-05-2011","09-02-2012",
                           "07-11-2011","07-03-2012","05-07-2011","03-05-2011",
                           "02-12-2011","01-11-2011","01-08-2011","01-06-2011"];


function unavailable(date) {
    dmy = date.getDate() + "-"+ (date.getMonth() + 1) +"-" + date.getFullYear();
    if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
        return [false, "Unavailable"];
    } else {
        return [true, "", ""];
    }
}

$(function() {
$("#iDate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    beforeShowDay: unavailable,
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
        $('#frmDate').submit();
     }
  });
});
```

For some reason it is populating some of the datepicker controller with some dates from the array, but omitting others. I have no idea why it is behaving this way.

Can somebody help?

Thank you.

Comment: I suspect this could be a date format/interpretation issue: `DD-MM-YYYY` vs `MM-DD-YYYY`.

Comment: Yes it doesn't seem to like the dates being in the following format: 01-06-2011 e.g. a 0 being before the month digit....However I dont understand why this is a problem when I have defined the format as  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'

Comment: How do I get the datepicker to accept that format?

Comment: If you're defining the dateFormat as yy-mm-dd, why is your array in the format dd-mm-yyyy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unavailable() contains faulty logic. When getDate() and getMonth() return single digit number,  you try to find date that does not exist in you array. For example you search "1-8-2011" instead of "01-08-2011".
One solution is to left pad your date parts with zeroes when necessary.

[JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/YMBfL/).